# How to retrieve data from sql server and put into a combo box using C#?

Tags: c#

I have a SQL database table create on Visual Studio. Now I want to access that database, read its value based on a certain column and save those value into the combo box list.

For example, if I have a table like this

```
|StudentName    | Age    | ID    |
|---------------|--------|-------|
|A              | 19     | 1     |
|---------------|--------|-------|
|B              | 15     | 2     |
|---------------|--------|-------|
|C              | 20     | 3     |
|---------------|--------|-------|
```

and a combo box named nameCombo, what I want is to have something like this

```
nameCombo.Items.Add(A);
nameCombo.Items.Add(B);
nameCombo.Items.Add(C);
```

How am I going to do this ? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Assuming that you have already connect LINQ to your SQL database. Here is what you should do to update your combo box. All thanks to those awesome guys here in stackoverflow.

```
locationLinqToSQLDataContext db = new locationLinqToSQLDataContext();
var nameData = from name in db.Locations
               select new { name.StudentName };

foreach (var name in nameData)
    {
        fromTextBox.Items.Add(name.StudentName);
    }
```

Comment: Can you use LINQ2SQL ?

Comment: @xsari3x: yes I can.

Comment: Solved down there :)

Comment: Usually when you have a drop down you want to store both the value to identify your data programmatically and display the data that makes sense to the user.  At a minimum you should set the ID as the value and the student name to display.  Otherwise you are forced to search for the string studentName when someone picks the value.  Alternatively you could just store the entire object in the drop down and you have it when they select the value, saves trips to the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok assuming LINQ then:

Query it out into a list.

```
var myData = (from d in db.MyTable
              where d.Name.contains("A")
              select d).ToList();
```

Then assign it to the combo:

```
mycombo.datasource=myData;
mycombo.dataTextField="Name";
mycombo.dataValueField="ID";
mycombo.dataBind();
```

Just made this up on the fly but it should work.

OR If you really want to iterate the items.

```
myData.foreach(delegate(MyTableItem i) 
{
    mycombo.add(new listitem(i.id,i.name));
});
```

Comment: the way that you did only works on a certain element that you already know in the table (such as A). My question is, regardless of what is in the name column, it will be query out into a list. Is there a better way to do it with Linq ?

Comment: Thats just an example, you could just as easily make "A" a variable and compare it to Name, or any other field.  It appeared as though the question was more related to data binding.  If you want to do multi-column dynamic queries that's a whole other problem and is LINQ related.  I would take a look at LINQ Kit which will let you build dynamic and well typed LINQ queries.

Comment: thanks, I finally figured out how to do it. I'll edit my question with the answer

Answer (score 2):

If you need it for windows form application here is the code:

```
       DataTable dt = new DataTable("dataTable");

        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        //add DataRow
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Id"] = 1;
        row["Name"] = "One";

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        //assign to ComboBox
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
```

For web applications you can see the other answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses `SqlConnection` (which naively assumes you don't need data binding). Of course you must replace "YourConnectionString" and "YourTable" with real values.

```
string connectionString = "YourConnectionString";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    string query = "SELECT Name FROM YourTable";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // "0" refers to the 0th column in the result set.
            nameCombo.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }
    }
}
```